# adjoint orbit of (twisted) loop group

Tags: loop-groups

Let $G$ be the twisted loop group of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ and let $g$ be its Lie algebra, where diagonal entries are even functions and off diagonal entries are odd functions (of loop parameter lambda).

> What are the adjoint orbits in $g$?
>
> Is the adjoint orbit structure known for all the (twisted) loop groups over complex simple Lie groups?

Comment: What sort of structure on the adjoint orbits are you seeking?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a normal form for an element in a loop algebra under formal adjoint action. For example in the ordinary sl_2(C) case, adjoint orbits are classified by determinant function, etc.